# I need to copy computers from the default active directory "container" to security group using powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to remove all computers from the `wk_test` security group and then add all the computers in the default 'Computers' container in AD to the (now-empty) `wk_test` security group.

However, I don't want to export the computers to a list and then import them back into the security group.

I have the first part of the script working properly, and it removes the computers from the wk_test group with no errors. My issue is adding the computers to the wk_test group from the "computers" container.

```
Remove-ADGroupMember "wk_test" -Members (Get-ADGroupMember "wk_test") -Confirm:$false 
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "wk_test" -Members (Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "CN=computers,DC=ad,dc=org") -filter*
```

I think the main problem is that I am attempting to copy from the computers container. Most of the advice on the internet refers to copying from an OU and not a container.

Comment: For what you are doing a Container and OU will act the same, you just reference them differently: `CN=computers` versus `OU=my_ou`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Add-ADGroupMember` [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee617210.aspx) says:

> You cannot pass user, computer, or group objects through the pipeline to this cmdlet.

Which I think is what you are trying to do.

I've used this method before to add computers from an OU to a group:

```
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "CN=computers,DC=ad,dc=org" -Filter * | foreach {Add-ADGroupMember "wk_test" -Members $_.DistinguishedName }
```

But I think you could also modify your code like this, but I've not tested this as I'm not on domain at the moment.

```
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "CN=computers,DC=ad,dc=org" -filter* | select -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "wk_test" -Members $Computers
```

Comment: Thanks James C. for the script. Items fixed- not a space between -filter and *.  Also found I had put the last DC=org instead of DC=local, -fixed and it worked great. Combined both and they both run but between the removal process and the add I have to hit the enter key to continue. I must have missed something. But it looks great. Thanks for all your help. Final script:   Remove-ADGroupMember "wk_test" -Members (Get-ADGroupMember "wk_test") -Confirm:$false 
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "CN=computers,DC=ad,dc=local" -Filter * | foreach {Add-ADGroupMember "wk_test" -Members $_.DistinguishedName}

Comment: James C. I have spent the last 2-3 hours trying to make it so the script will run with out pausing at the second command line. (no, I am not clicking in the PS window with the mouse) any ideas? both lines run fine. It just pauses between the remove and add lines until I hit enter.          Remove-ADGroupMember "wk_CPSI_test" -Members (Get-ADGroupMember "wk_CPSI_test") -Confirm:$false 
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "CN=computers,DC=ad,dc=local" -Filter * | foreach {Add-ADGroupMember "wk_cpsi_test" -Members $_.DistinguishedName}

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving them, why not use `Move-ADObject`. 
So it would be:

```
Get-ADGroupMember "wk_test" | Move-ADObject -TargetPath <ou path>
```

Comment: I need to copy them. It is a complicated explanation, but I can't move them due to inter-departmental issues (Politics)